# component not rendering after setState in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to render a component conditionally based on a particular state. The code below is inside of a mapping on another file. I have a setState const of open and whenever a user clicks the 'comment' button it should be setting the openState to true. However, when I click the comment button it does not open the modal. The modal is passed a prop of `open={open}` and i'm still not getting it to open.

here is the code

```
  const { blog, idx, id } = props


  const [open, setOpen] = useState({});
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="blogBox" id={id} key={idx}>
        <h4>{blog.title}</h4>
        <hr />
        <p>{blog.body}</p>
        <hr />
        <p id="postedBy">Posted By: Claude @ {blog.createdAt}</p>
        <hr />
        <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={handleOpen}>Comment</button>
        <HandleNoteModal open={open} onClose={handleClose} />
        <hr />
        <div className="comment Section">
          <span>User 1:</span>
          <span> Comment one</span>
          <br />
          <span>User 2:</span>
          <span> Comment two</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )

}
```

I'm wondering if i need to be passing the prop inside the other component as well as passing it in here on this file. my `<HandleNoteModal />` component was created on another file and then imported.

for safe keeping and time, here is the code for my HandleNoteModal component.

````
  const { handleClose } = props
  const [noteState, setNoteState] = useState({
    user: '',
    note: ''
  });

  const handleInputChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setNoteState({ ...noteState, [name]: value });
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="modal" tabIndex="-1">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title">Leave a Comment</h5>
            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="note" className="form-label">Comment:</label>
                <textarea name="note" className="form-control formBody" placeholder="Enter comment here" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
} ```
````

Comment: The key thing to check `HandleNoteModal` is `open` prop, but seemingly you haven't shared it in `HandleNoteModal` code. Please show how you integrate `open` prop in that component

Comment: If i set the return statement inside a condition of if (open === true) within the HandleNoteModal component
it still doesn't render

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case, you don't need to pass `open` prop to validate opening or closing that modal component

You just put a conditional check on your upper component like below

```
{open && <HandleNoteModal onClose={handleClose} />}
```

Here is how it looks like in your code

```
const { blog, idx, id } = props


  const [open, setOpen] = useState({});
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="blogBox" id={id} key={idx}>
        <h4>{blog.title}</h4>
        <hr />
        <p>{blog.body}</p>
        <hr />
        <p id="postedBy">Posted By: Claude @ {blog.createdAt}</p>
        <hr />
        <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={handleOpen}>Comment</button>
        {open && <HandleNoteModal onClose={handleClose} />}
        <hr />
        <div className="comment Section">
          <span>User 1:</span>
          <span> Comment one</span>
          <br />
          <span>User 2:</span>
          <span> Comment two</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it is still not opening the modal.

Comment: I created a sanbox here (https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-maxwell-iclzgw?file=/src/App.js) to simulate your case. Seemingly it's working with the simulation, could you tell me more about which error you get? @ClaudeM

Comment: It isn't hitting me with any erreors it's just not triggering the modal render at all.

Comment: this is however being rendered from within the map of another component and  I think this may also be posing an issue for the code.

Comment: could you share that map part with me? @ClaudeM

Comment: just edditted the post .

Comment: Could you share your full modal component too? @ClaudeM